# The IF - OR condition does not work with Float(nan) in python. How to write this in a single line?

Tags: python, pandas

There are 4 conditions mainly :

1. str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Payment"
2. str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Contra" and row["Withdrawal*"] is not null
3. str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Receipt"
4. str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Contra" and str(row["Deposit*"]) is not null

For 1 and 2, the value should be
amount.text = str(row["Withdrawal*"] * -1)

But for 3,4 the value should be amount.text = str(row["Deposit*"] * -1)

So, I am trying hard to combine them into 2 conditions, as below, but its always failing to identify "and" condition in the if statement properly and giving me a NaN for condition 2.

What is wrong in this code?

```
    if str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Payment" or (str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Contra" and row["Withdrawal*"] != '']):
        amount.text = str(row["Withdrawal*"] * -1)
    elif str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Receipt" or (str(row["Vch Type*"]) == "Contra" and str(row["Deposit*"]) != ''):
        amount.text = str(row["Deposit*"])
    else:
        x = 0
```

Note : In debug mode, i can see that row["Withdrawal*"] is NaN in condition 2 and row["Deposit*"] is NaN in condition 4. So, i saw some posts to compare a float NaN using below, but even that is not working. Is there any way to combine this into a single if statement? if not atleast into 2 instead of 4.??

float('nan') == float('nan')

> False

Comment: Don't use `iterrows`/`apply`, build vectorial conditions  and use `np.select`

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't know why are you checking `notna` with `!=''` condition, but in your first condition, you didn't convert `row["Withdrawal*"] ` to string before checking it.

Comment: Yes, Sorry The fastest way to solve this was convert to string and compare with the string as 'nan'. then it would work! Thanks